# jQueryUI slider how to remove handle border

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have successfully changed the background image，just a yellow border which appear each time i click the handle. This border remains until i click somewhere else in the page. Moreover this border is blinking each time the handle is moved.
[Someone had the same problem befor](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/theming-slider-handle-border)
But no one has replied.

How can i remove this border ?

this is my page (temporary link removed)

Comment: Please put your code with questions so S.O. will help you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
.ui-slider a {outline:none;} /* a img { outline:none } for reference
```

I think it's a default of some browsers when an inline image is used as a hyperlink.

Chrome and Safari and FF showed it in one form or another:
Safari showed it as blue, FF showed it as a dotted outline...

IE6, IE7 showed nothing.

** **Edit** **
Rather than removing the outline, you may consider styling it to suite your design. This tells a keyboard-user that the handle is now focused, if your slider is accessible/arrow-key-friendly.

```
.ui-slider a:focus { outline:1px dotted gray }
```

Comment: T_T,i just realised IE still has problems, do u know how could i solve it?

Comment: NP - Welcome to SO. Good luck with the rest of your project.

Comment: Try clearing your cache (<shift>+Reload, or manually). I can no longer reproduce the effect on my end - since you added the fix.

Comment: In IE, there are 2 more handle background images shown on the page, one is in the middle of the page(can be seen after maximize the browser window)， the other one can be seen after slide the handle to 0，there is one background image remained in the middle

Comment: If it bothers you, you can also remove them like that: `*{outline:none;}`

Comment: Do not use `*` as a hail mary in CSS. *{outline:none} is equivalent to p,em,i,b,strong,div,body,a,img,table,tr,td,span,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,etc. {outline:none} <-- you'd never do this. Why create the overhead? And it negates accessibility for keyboard-only users.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if this is better/worse than the given answer, but from what I can tell I think I prefer the way I have always done this before I came across this thread, and thought I would share it with others for future reference if anyone wanted to do it like this. I got good results. I think this specifically targets the actual handle more precisely:

Add this to your css file:

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle:focus { outline: none; }
```

Comment: This answer should be marked as correct answer, really awesome trick.

Comment: Agree with @Ranjit - this worked for me, not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma in your document css

`.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,`

It also isn't being applied to an image but an a tag so

`img { border:none; }`

shouldn't work.

Comment: it's not the  comma, since i already have a `,.ui-state-focus,`  before     `.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,`